# Using a Solr filter query (fq) as a LocalParam appears to get ignored

Tags: solr

I'm trying to make a query with a sub-query in my boost parameter. The boost parameter looks like this:

```
boost=if(exists(query({!dismax qf='title' fq='type:company' v=$q})), 2, 1)
```

Some sort of boosting seems to take place, but it also seems like `fq` is completely ignored. I mean, it literally doesn't matter what I write. The result remains the same. If I change `qf` to `body` or something else, this clearly effects the result. If I change `2, 1` to `9999, 1`, this has no effect.

What am I doing wrong here? Why won't `fq` work? Why doesn't it matter if I write `2, 1` or `9999, 1`?

---

This is actually my continued attempt to do what is described in another question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287255/how-to-boost-in-solr-when-a-specific-field-matches-q-and-another-condition-is-m/20288250#20288250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using something like this:

```
boost=if(exists(query({!v='type:company'})), if(exists(query({!v='state:0'})), if(exists(query({!dismax qf='title' v=$q})), 2, 1), 1), 1)
```

So far it seems to do what I want to do. Not the prettiest thing around.